# How to ignore specified files in commit at Visual Studio in all projects?

Tags: git, visual-studio, commit

I'm working on Windows 10 with project using Visual Studio 2019.
I didn't want to commit some files.
In my .gitconfig I have:

```
[core]
    excludesfile = C:/Users/sadamski/.gitignore_global
```

and in .gitignore_global I have such files:

```
web.config
launchSettings.json
package-lock.json
package.json
```

and it doesn't work. Visual Studio commits them.

I want to not remember about that files in commiting and not commit them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shell expansion by executing this command :

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

Comment: It was done before. You can see the result in my .gitconfig.

Comment: you need to execute the command after modifying your .gitconfig like this :
[core]
        excludesfile = .gitignore_global

Comment: Ok, I done it after too. Did not help.